# How to change diagonal elements in a matrix from 1 to 0, 0 to 1

Tags: python, numpy

Please can someone help with flipping elements on the diagonal of a matrix from 1 to 0 if 1, and 0 to 1 if 0 for the matrix `rmat`

```
mat = np.random.binomial(1,.5,4)
rmat = np.array([mat,]*4)
```

Thank you

Comment: can you try to explain a little better what you are going for?

Comment: I would like to change the diagonal elements of a matrix whose rows are all duplicates. So if the diagonal is 1, it becomes 0, vice versa. So the new matrix should be identical to the original, except for the diagonals have all been flipped

Comment: can you tag as numpy and not pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html).

*NB. the operation is **in place***

```
diagonal = rmat.diagonal()
np.fill_diagonal(rmat, 1-diagonal)
```

input:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: for some reason, it prints ```none```?

Comment: As I said, the operation is **in place**, it does not return a value but modifies `rmat`

Comment: try `print(rmat)` after you have done the `fill_diagonal` operation

Comment: okay, thanks. Is there a wy to make this a new variable?

Comment: `new_mat = rmat.copy()` then apply the operation on `new_mat`

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

Unlike the `np.fill_diagonal`, this method is not inplace and doesnt need explicit copy of the input rmat matrix.

```
n = rmat.shape[0]
output = np.where(np.eye(n, dtype=bool), np.logical_not(rmat), rmat)
output
```

```
#Original
[[0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]]

#diagonal inverted
[[1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]]
```

---

Another way to do this would be to use `np.diag_indices` along with `np.logical_not`

```
n = rmat.shape[0]
idx = np.diag_indices(n)

rmat[idx] = np.logical_not(rmat[idx])
print(rmat)
```

Comment: for some reason, it prints ```none```

Comment: are hyou running this after running some other code? Try remaking the rmat matrix and then run

Comment: this is an inplace operation. you will have to recreate the rmat matrix if you have already modified it

Comment: @mozway added addition methods, one using `np.where` and another using `np.diag_indices`